# Which is other alternative compiler for turbo C++

Tags: c++

I am learning turbo C++ and I don't like the old Turbo C++ blue color compiler.

Is there any graphical IDE and compiler for C++ like Eclipse or any other so that I have full power of copy-paste as well?

Comment: `Turbo C++` is a compiler, not a language. Get visual c++, or.... eclipse + cdt

Comment: Even with VIM you have "full power of copy-paste"...

Comment: "Full power" of... what?! o_O

Comment: From memory, I think you can configure the background to be something other than blue. ;-P

Comment: I vote for pink! Upvote this if you agree!

Comment: Pretty sure the last time I touched TurboC++ was 1997...

Comment: i don't know but i find compiling easy in turboc++ and find very hard to compile in visual c++. also there are no graphics in visual c++

Comment: @paddy , you r right i did c++ in year 1999 , now i am learning again . i thought the world is still there. don't know what happened after 1999 to c++

Comment: When you say there are no graphics in Visual C++, what do you mean?  Certainly, the days of poking bytes straight onto your video card in VGA mode are gone.

Comment: @paddy so what people do now days for graphics. i looks like i woken from sleep after 12 years

Comment: You should look at Direct3D or OpenGL.  If you were expecting to be able to start writing pixels to memory, you're probably gonna hate it, but eventually you'll see how powerful it is.  NeHe has some great tutorials for legacy OpenGL at [http://nehe.gamedev.net/](http://nehe.gamedev.net/).  Even though the immediate-mode stuff has been replaced in newer versions of OpenGL, it's a good starting point and it should still work.  On current drivers, at least.

Answer (score 2):

An IDE is what you are looking for. The compiler only does the work on the background. There are many very good IDEs for C++. I would recommend either using [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) or [Microsoft Visual Studio Express C++](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products).

Both have much more than copy paste, which is code autocompletion. It will be your best friend  soon enough.

Answer (score -1):

Why still use turbo C++ in 21th century?

You should use gcc(g++ for compile c++ program) as your compiler and use vi/emacs as your editor.